# How to express a C++ or GLM struct as a numpy array?

Tags: python, numpy, opengl, glsl, glm-math

I want to express the below struct into as numpy array.

```
struct UniformBufferObject {
    glm::mat4 model;
    glm::mat4 view;
    glm::mat4 proj;
};
```

Thereafter, the numpy array is meant to be read in as a GLSL layout:

```
layout(binding = 0) uniform UniformBufferObject {
    mat4 model;
    mat4 view;
    mat4 proj;
} ubo;
```

In the above statements, `mat4` denotes a 4x4 matrix.

Below, I created a python list which I then converts to a numpy array (w/o copying) with a 4x4 shape where each element is a `dtype=float32`.

**Question:** What should I do next to represent the `UniformBufferObject` struct as a numpy array?

```
>>> model = [0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0,]
>>> view = [0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 1, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 1, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 1, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0,]
>>> proj = [0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 1, 0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 1, 0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 1, 0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 0,]
>>> modeln = np.asarray(model, dtype= 'f4').reshape(4,4)
>>> viewn = np.asarray(view, dtype= 'f4').reshape(4,4)
>>> projn = np.asarray(proj, dtype= 'f4').reshape(4,4)
>>> modeln
array([[0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 1. ],
       [0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 1. ],
       [0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 1. ],
       [0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0. ]], dtype=float32)
>>> viewn
array([[0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 1. ],
       [0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 1. ],
       [0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 1. ],
       [0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0. ]], dtype=float32)
>>> projn
array([[0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 1. ],
       [0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 1. ],
       [0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 1. ],
       [0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 0. ]], dtype=float32)
>>>
```

Comment: `... gglm::mat4 model;` That is **not** C.

Comment: @wildplasser It is glm (based on C or C++?). But I think UniformBufferObject is a C struct that contains the glm objects. Or not? I may have to revise my question, but in essence is it possible to express the struct as a numpy array?

Comment: Add some tags for the non python stuf - c, glm or what ever.

Answer (score 1):

If in GLSL a [Uniform block](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Interface_Block_(GLSL)#Uniform_blocks) is specified like this

> ```
>  layout(binding = 0) uniform UniformBufferObject {
>      mat4 model;
>      mat4 view;
>      mat4 proj;
>  } ubo;
> ```

then OpenGL does not guarantee, that the members in th block are stored in consecutive order. OpenGL gives no guarantees about the memory layout, alignment or order of the elements.

To achieve a well defined order and memory layout the [memory layout qualifier `std140`](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Interface_Block_(GLSL)#Memory_layout) ahs to be used. The `std140` layout is provided since OpenGL 3.1 respectively OpenGL ES 3.0 or the OpenGL extension [*ARB_uniform_buffer_object*](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/extensions/ARB/ARB_uniform_buffer_object.txt):

```c
layout(std140, binding = 0) uniform UniformBufferObject {
    mat4 model;
    mat4 view;
    mat4 proj;
} ubo;
```

A detailed specification about the layout can be found at:

- [OpenGL 4.6 API Core Profile Specification; 7.6.2.2 Standard Uniform Block Layout; page 144](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/specs/gl/glspec46.core.pdf)
- [OpenGL 4.6 API Compatibility Profile Specification; 7.6.2.2 Standard Uniform Block Layout; page 145](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/specs/gl/glspec46.compatibility.pdf)
- [OpenGL ES 3.2 Specification; 7.6.2.2 Standard Uniform Block Layout; page 113](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/specs/es/3.2/es_spec_3.2.pdf)

In case of the above uniform block with `std140` layout the 3 matrices are tightly packed. The memory layout are 48 (3*4*4) *`float`s* in a row and has a size of 192 bytes

```
mat4 model     byte offset   0: size in bytes  64 = 4*4*sizeof(float)
mat4 view      byte offset  64: size in bytes  64 = 4*4*sizeof(float)
mat4 proj      byte offset 128: size in bytes  64 = 4*4*sizeof(float)
--------------------------------------------------------------------
                                size in bytes 192 = 3*4*4*sizeof(float)
```

To create a buffer which corresponds to this memory layout, a flat [`numpy.array`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/reference/generated/numpy.array.html) can be used:

e.g.

> ```
>  model = [0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0,]
>  view = [0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 1, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 1, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 1, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0,]
>  proj = [0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 1, 0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 1, 0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 1, 0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 0,]
> ```

```py
import numpy as np

ubo_data = np.array([model, view, proj], dtype='f4')
```

It is not necessary to [`reshap()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.1/reference/generated/numpy.reshape.html) the array. But of course you can do so, if you want to access the elements of the model matrix (`ubo_data[0]`), the view matrix (`ubo_data[1]`) and the projection matrix (`ubo_data[2]`) directly:

```py
ubo_data = np.array([model, view, proj], dtype='f4').reshape(3, 4, 4)
```

Note, it is even not necessary to use [NumPy](http://www.numpy.org/). A buffer with the same memory layout can be generated by a [ctypes](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ctypes.html) array:

```py
import ctypes

ubo_data = (ctypes.c_float * 48)(*model, *view, *proj)
```

Using [PyOpenGL](http://pyopengl.sourceforge.net/), each of the above data arrays can be used to crate and initialize the buffer store of a uniform block buffer by [`glBufferData`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glBufferData.xhtml)

```py
ubo = glGenBuffers( 1 )
glBindBuffer(GL_UNIFORM_BUFFER, ubo)
glBufferData(GL_UNIFORM_BUFFER, ubo_data, GL_STATIC_DRAW)
glBindBufferBase(GL_UNIFORM_BUFFER, 0, ubo)
glBindBuffer(GL_UNIFORM_BUFFER, 0)
```

or update the data store of an existing buffer by `glBufferSubData`:

```py
glBindBuffer(GL_UNIFORM_BUFFER, ubo)
glBufferSubData(GL_UNIFORM_BUFFER, 0, ubo_data)
```

Note, when using [PyGLM](https://pypi.org/project/PyGLM/), then the data of a uniform buffer like this can be updated directly:

e.g.:

```py
import glm
```

```py
model = glm.mat4(1)
view  = glm.lookAt(glm.vec3(0,-3,0), glm.vec3(0,0,0), glm.vec3(0,0,1))
proj  = glm.perspective(glm.radians(90), 800.0/600.0, 0.1, 100)

glBufferSubData(GL_SHADER_STORAGE_BUFFER, 0,                      glm.sizeof(glm.mat4), glm.value_ptr(model))
glBufferSubData(GL_SHADER_STORAGE_BUFFER, 1*glm.sizeof(glm.mat4), glm.sizeof(glm.mat4), glm.value_ptr(view))
glBufferSubData(GL_SHADER_STORAGE_BUFFER, 2*glm.sizeof(glm.mat4), glm.sizeof(glm.mat4), glm.value_ptr(proj))
```